# What does two numbers mean in react devtools flame chart

Tags: reactjs, react-devtools

I use react-devtools standalone package for profiling my react native app.
unlike what is shown in official devtools documentation, in my devtools there are two numbers on each bar in the flame chart.

[image]

What does each of these two numbers mean?

Comment: Do you mean execution time? Like 8 ms of 88.0 ms?  
My guess would be that it means the sepecific execution time.

Comment: In react devtools chrome extension there is a single number and that's the execution time. my question is that what is the second number (eg. 80ms in 8ms of 80ms)
My first thought was that it is the total time of the commit. but if you become more precise you see that is different for each bar. so what is that?

Comment: Apparently, the first time metric is the instance when the commit was made, and the second one is the time it took for it to re-render.   
Or maybe it's another thing
https://elijahmanor.com/react-devtools-profiler/